# Pythagorean triplets using python's list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, pythagorean

I can find out Pythagorean triplets using for loop as follows:

```
def triplet(n): # Find all the Pythagorean triplets between 1 and n (inclusive)
  for a in range(n+1):
    for b in range(a):
      for c in range(b):
        if a*a == b*b + c*c:
          print(a, b, c)
```

I wanted to replace this with a one-liner using list comprehension and tried the following piece:

```
[a, b, c in range(n+1), range(a), range(b) if a*a == b*b + c*c]
```

But, I get a syntax error on the closing square bracket. I tried to change the list into tuple using simple brackets, but with no success. May I know how to get it right?

Comment: Using the relevant number theory would be much more efficient than an `O(n^3)` brute force.

Comment: Thanks. My aim was to find a list comprehension equivalent of a nested for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean

```
[(a,b,c) for a in range(n+1) for b in range(a) for c in range(b) if a*a == b*b + c*c]
```

That at least is syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1):

**Notice:** This solution is only for the problem when `a + b + c <= N`

Asssume that a<=b<=c, this version is a little faster:

```
triplet = [(a,b,c) for a in range(1,N//3+1) for b in range(a,N//2+1) for c in range(b,N-1) if a**2 + b**2 == c**2]
```

Comment: No. This does not generate all the triplets within a given N. For example, when N = 100, (13, 84, 85) is not listed.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It seems that my solution is for the problem when a + b + c <= N, which is not the case here. I will fix that.